# Ошибки при установке пакетов npm

Tags: node.js, npm

Установлен свеженький Node.js, при установке любого пакета Gulp, AngularCli выдает одни и теже ошибки.

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.14393
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code EPROTO
npm ERR! errno EPROTO
npm ERR! syscall write

npm ERR! write EPROTO 101057795:error:140943FC:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad record mac:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:1493:SSL alert number 20
npm ERR! 101057795:error:1409E0E5:SSL routines:ssl3_write_bytes:ssl handshake failure:openssl\ssl\s3_pkt.c:659:
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\liza\project\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: Судя вот по этому примеру https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3692#issuecomment-154899692 это какой-то баг в npm. попробуйте обновиться. npm v3 довольно старый.